# Using below code i want to to ScrollTop 1px the dynamic tabs on active of every content

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

On active I want dynamic home-tab-content to be scroll by `1px` in every click.

```
$('.home-menu-div ol').click(function(){
    var ref = $(this).data('ref');
    $('.home-tab-content').hide();
    $('#home-tab-content'+ref).fadeIn();
    $(".home-menu-div ol").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

http://192.168.1.200/

Comment: [Check out JQuery's `.scrollTop()` method](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollTop to a specific element. For example if you want to scroll the body element in one px you do this:

```
$('body').scrollTop( $('body').scrollTop() + 1 );
```